# Arranging array of String from bytes

Tags: java, string, file

I am new to java and trying to process some logic. I have file

```
5049,INF
5049,INF
5049,INF
5049,INF
5049,INF
5051,INF
5051,INF
5051,BNF
5051,TNF
```

I need this file data in string concatenation like

pIntString value is 5049,5051 and pString value is INF,BNF,TNF.

My Java Code

```
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    String str = new String(data);
    //System.out.println(data.toString());
    String[] strValue = str.split(",");
    String pushidString = null;
    String pIntString = strValue[0];

    for (int i=0;i<strValue.length-2;i++) {

        pushidString = strValue[i+2];
        pIntString = pushidString + pIntString;


    }
```

But this code lack basic logic. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code covers what you're asking for, by:

- Reading the lines of the file one at a time
- Keeping track of the columns' values in `List` data structures
- Looping through the columns and outputting values separated by commas

Code:

```
public void showFileContents() throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get(this.getClass().getResource("bar.txt").getPath());

    // read each line one at a time
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

    List<String> firstColumn = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> secondColumn = new ArrayList<>();

    // Loop through each line and do whatever you want with them
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] strValue = line.split(",");
        firstColumn.add(strValue[0]);
        secondColumn.add(strValue[1]);
    }

    // Looks like you wanted them separated by columns in one String, so that looks like:
    System.out.println("Values from first column:");
    System.out.println(String.join(",", firstColumn));
    System.out.println("Values from second column:");
    System.out.println(String.join(",", secondColumn));
}
```

This test class uses a file named `bar.txt` with the contents described in the original post, located in the same location on disk as the method itself.